# xcode 11 Close secondary editor shortcut

Tags: xcode11

Is there a shortcut to close all other editors except focused one?

Previously I would open a file with option so it would show as a second editor. When I was done with the second editor, I would "close" it by using show editor only (command + return). With xcode 11, the second editor isn't part of the assistant editor. So, I can't "close" it with show editor only.

In simple terms.. Is there a shortcut to close the right editor and only show the left one.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think **SHIFT+CONTROL+CMD+RETURN** is exactly what you are looking for (Note: you should be "focused" on left editor to close right).

Helpful link about new Xcode 11 assistant editor behavior:
https://www.avanderlee.com/xcode/xcode-assistant-editor/

Comment: Yes -- This is shortcut answers my question. However, this seems to be a toggle.. So if I want to open a new editor, I would need to use the shortcut again.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. This toggles the secondary editor, as in, you can't use a secondary editor at all if you don't toggle it back.

Answer (score 6):

The shortcut to close the current active editor is:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> + <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100620/957245) answer contains many more options